# How to call a table valued function from Visual Basic.Net and how to store the result

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

In my VB.net code i have:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [strfg].[dbo].[Myfunc] (@MyParam)"
    Dim myparam As New SqlParameter("@MyParam", a)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(myparam)
```

The function (runnig on SQL server) returns a table with four columns, one row.

How do I call this function from Visual Basic? cmd.ExecuteScalar() is obviously not correct. In c++ I use a recordset. What is the equivalent in vb? Does anyone have a short example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader
Dim MyList as new List(Of WhateverObject)
Do While reader.Read
    Dim obj as new WhateverObj
    obj.Property1 = Reader.GetInt32(0)
    obj.Property2 = Reader.GetString(1)
    MyList.add(obj)
Loop

reader.Close()
cmd.Dispose()
```

Where you use the index value based on the order of the returned fields, and its type in the Get.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is similar to a recordset consider using a datatable. Your code can look like:

```
    Dim custId As String = "ALFKI"

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers Where CustomerId=@CustomerId", conn)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", custId)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

The datatable has a collection of Rows which contains your data.